# Angular app served by Node.js without JS scripts

Tags: node.js, angular

I created an Angular app with a node.js server. When I serve the app locally ('ng serve'), the app works fine. However, when i build the Angular project into a 'public' folder, and set the node.js server to serve the web pages of the app, the browser displays the HTML code served by the server as text.

The node.js code that serves the pages is the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const authRouter = require('./src/middlewares/auth.js');
const roomRouter = require('./src/middlewares/room.js');
const controller = require('./src/middlewares/token.js');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

///////////////////////////////////////
//////////// MIDDLEWARES //////////////
///////////////////////////////////////

app.use(bodyParser.json()) //Parsed data is populated on the request object (i.e. req.body).
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true }))
app.use( (req, res, next ) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept, x-access-token')
  if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH')
  }
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json') //REST-API: we only send back json data
  next()
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//////////////////////////////
///////// DATABASE ///////////
//////////////////////////////
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sync';
var db;
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(client => {
    console.log("connection to database established...  ");

    db = client.db("sync");
    db.createCollection('users'); //Normally, if it already exists, it shoudn't do anything, but I'm not sure

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      req.db = db
      next();
    })

  })
  .catch(err => {console.log(err)})

///////////////////
//// ROUTING //////
///////////////////

app.use('/api/auth', authRouter)
app.use('/api/room', roomRouter)

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
   // res.send('Hello')
});


///////////////////////////////////////
///////// SOCKET CONNECTION ///////////
///////////////////////////////////////

var sockets = [];

const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //socket.on...
    //...
});


///////////////////////////////////////
///////// SERVER CONNECTION ///////////
///////////////////////////////////////

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Running on port " + PORT)
})
```

The index.html file is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Client2</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect the web page served by the server, only the index.html is sent and not the scripts linked to it, hence not being able to display the page correctly. it's as if express doesn't serve the javascript files.

Comment: Can you please share the whole *.js file?

Comment: Done. I am still working with a local database though. I don't know if this will have any effect on serving the web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.sendFile()` is an express function to send a file (https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.sendFile). So, the headers will be set accordingly. Use the express function `res.send()` to correctly set the response and look at http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html .

Even better: use a simple http-server like nginx oder the npm tool http-server for your serving purpose.

Comment: I think that the problem is not the 'sendFile' function. Even when i change it to 'res.send('Hello')', the code of the index.html file located in the public folder is still sent and displayed as text. I suspect there is a problem with the 'express.static' line.

Comment: Please take a look at the second part of my answer. Why not using a dedicated http-server? Ist your project dependend on a self build server?

Comment: I am using a free Heroku account for hosting my website for now. Heroku doesn't provide a static IP address for the server, and I don't know how to setup nginx without using ssh. Is it possible to use nginx with Heroku?

Comment: @AchrafElKhamsi unfortunatly, i cannot help you with this, as i have no  deeper experience with heroku. Please consult the docs as a first step.